# Does npm touch anything besides the node_modules folder when installing a package locally?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm only curious about installing packages locally in a project - not globally.

Is there any difference between `npm uninstall some-package` and just deleting the some-package folder from the node_modules directory?

Comment: If the package you're installing has an install script then it can touch anything it wants. The documentation notes that you shouldn't, but doesn't mean one _can't_. (https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading that: https://npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html I would say no. There is no difference, when using local modules between `npm uninstall` and deleting the directory.

However, I think the `/tmp` directory is used when there is additional process during the installation (Compilation, etc...). Therefore, it is possible that the uninstall command remove those files if needed (But I can't see that in the present documentation)

My two cents

Comment: That is exactly the docs page I was looking for. Thank you! This is a surprisingly difficult question to search for.